# Непонятная работа исходящих запросов

Tags: linux, сеть, tcp, tcp-ip

У меня хостинг hetzner, закрыты порты все кроме 80,22,8080.
Когда пишу `curl https://www.google.de/` все работает нормально, 
пишу `curl https://ru.stackoverflow.com` просто виснет.
Сначала думал что это DNS, потом ввёл  `curl 141.105.65.113` тоже виснет. 
Из за чего может быть проблема ?
(iptables сброшен(наверное))

Comment: вполне может быть забанен на стороне stackoverflow.com адрес Вашего сервера. Да, и ip stackoverflow  у меня другие. А Ваш ip - это wikileaks.org. Никто случайно hosts файл не поправил?

Comment: нет, hosts пустой

Comment: у мня даже curl ppa.launchpad.net не робит

Comment: Нужны логи, как минимум: `curl -v ` и провести трассировку: `tracepath`. Используете прокси через ssh туннель ?

Comment: скорее всего у хеснера проблема с роутингом. Когда то подобное было. Решилось письмом в саппорт.

Comment: @KoVadim Хорошо, напишу